# Как считать сообщения чатов, каналов телеграма по ключевым словам узнавать username отправившего сообщение?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

Написал код на python telethon, который выдает сообщения чата, но не понимаю, как отобрать сообщения по ключевым словам и занести в список, который можно будет вывести на экран, а также необходимо username отправившего сообщение. можно ли это реализовать?
на данный момент мой код:

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient

#настройка подключения
api_id = ''
api_hash = ''
session = 'anon'

client = TelegramClient(session, api_id, api_hash)
client.start()

username = input('Введите username чата: ')
chat = client.get_entity(username)

data_message = []
part_mes = client.get_messages(chat)
print(part_mes)
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

пробовал также через GetHistoryRequest, не получается, не понимаю, как правильно раскидать то, что выводит part_mes и как отобрать сообщения по ключевым словам